# jQuery show() won't turn Bootstrap d-none class visible

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm 99% sure I'm missing something terribly obvious here. On the next example, clicking the button should make the div with the `.progress` class visible. however, it is not working.

```js
function func() {
  $('.progress').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="progress d-none">
  No longer hidden!
</div>

<button onclick="func()">
  click me
</button>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The issue here is that the `d-none` utility class from **Bootstrap 4** adds the next `CSS` style to the `.progress` element:

```
.d-none {
  display: none!important;
}
```

On the other hand, when you invoke the `show()` method from **jQuery**, it adds the `display: block` style to the mentioned element. However, the previous style still has priority over this one, and the element remains hidden. This is due to the `!important` clause, for details you can give a read to the next link:

[What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)

So, the alternative (or good practice) is to remove the `d-none` class from the item you want to show.

```
function func()
{
    $('.progress').removeClass("d-none");
}
```

## Example:

On the next example, the `d-none` class is toggled in order to change the visibility of the `.progress` element:

```js
function func()
{
    $('.progress').toggleClass("d-none");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2 class="progress mt-2 d-none bg-warning">
    No longer hidden!
  </h2>

  <button onclick="func()" class="btn btn-primary">
    click me
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

jquery's show is not compatible with bootstrap's d-none. You can use Collapse - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/ - instead

Comment: Alas, the `d-none` class is still stronger.

Comment: @Gleb if you use .collapse instead of .d-none, you can use bootstrap's collapse function instead of jQuery's show function. Read the details in the link that's been in my answer for more than 2 years, it tells you how to solve the problem.

Comment: I search for a possiibility to open the block with the `.d-none` class by any method from jQuery or Bootstrap. My comment is just a resume that the `.d-none` class  is stronger as the `.collapse()` method: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/YzWNXjV

Answer (score 4):

When you not sure how your element hidden, with Bootstrap's `d-none`, or with regular `display: none`, but you need to make it visible in any case, just use following code:

```
$(el).removeClass("d-none").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own function like below.

```
$.fn.bsShow = function(){
    $(this).removeClass('d-none');
}

$.fn.bsHide = function(){
    $(this).addClass('d-none');
}
```

and then you can use like normal jQuery show/hide function.

```
$(".progress").bsShow();
$(".progress").bsHide();
```